No application apart from Gnome default screenshot taking app works for me on Ubuntu. How can I fix that?
So, on Windows, I've been using the Lightshot app, which allows me to easily annotate screenshots before copying them. I wanted something similar on Ubuntu.
At first, I tried Flameshot, however, it didn't properly work. By that I mean that it didn't work from system tray and I could only open it from the Terminal, but even then desktop suddenly enlarged and I couldn't see everything. Last time I tried, the whole screen just went white and I had to turn my display off and on again.
Then I tried all others I could find, but to no avail. Every time I either get a message that it failed to take a screenshot or it didn't even start or the whole UI just froze. I tried Shutter, Ksnip and many more.
Here's my setup. I have a standard Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS installation, using Ubuntu on Wayland. I have HP laptop docked to my USB-C Dell display, which is my primary. I have turned on fractional scaling, so 125% on my Dell display and 150% on my laptop display.
Is there anything I can do (apart from removing the fractional scaling) to make any of these work? It's infuriating.
